# Explicitly scope a variable inside a function vs closure

Tags: javascript

I have the 'phone_dlg_manager' constructor function and its private methods `show` and `init_country_code_combobox`. The dialog reference is held in the `phone_dlg` variable. The `show` method triggers `init_country_code_combobox` and I have two options:

1) Explicitly pass the variable `country_combobox` that the `init_country_code_combobox` methods needs:

```
function phone_dlg_manager(ctx, open_dlg_button, edit_ctrl, item)
{
    var phone_dlg;
    show();
    function show()
    {
        phone_dlg = ctx.application.ui.create_dialog(0, "PhoneEditorDlg");
        init_country_code_combobox(phone_dlg.country);
        read_to_dialog_controls(this._form_item);
        phone_dlg.visible = true;
    }

    function init_country_code_combobox(country_combobox)
    {       
        country_combobox.items.clear();
        country_combobox.items.start_adding();
        country_combobox.items.finish_adding();
    }
}
```

2) Since `phone_dlg` is accessible withing `init_country_code_combobox` through closure, I can access the property that I need without explicitly passing the variable:

```
function phone_dlg_manager(ctx, open_dlg_button, edit_ctrl, item)
{
    var phone_dlg;
    show();
    function show()
    {
        phone_dlg = ctx.application.ui.create_dialog(0, "PhoneEditorDlg");
        init_country_code_combobox(phone_dlg.country);
        read_to_dialog_controls(this._form_item);
        phone_dlg.visible = true;
    }

    function init_country_code_combobox()
    {       
        var country_combobox = phone_dlg.country;
        country_combobox.items.clear();
        country_combobox.items.start_adding();
        country_combobox.items.finish_adding();
    }
}
```

The second option seems easier to understand when reading code, however it makes the `init_country_code_combobox` function know more than it needs. Which option should I choose?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly a matter of style. Option 1 is a little cleaner, and more extensible, since you can use `init_country_code_combobox()` to initialize more than just the one dialog. But if this is unlikely to be necessary, option 2 is not unreasonable.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! So I'd probably go with the option 2 then, since someone reading my code may not understand the reasons for explicitly passing the variable.